# How to create an irregular textview or container?

Tags: android, textview, shapes

i m creating a chatting application in android and just i want to change the view of textview for previewing the comments

textview has a rectangle shape but i want to change it such as below photo that i mentioned...

i searched a lot but because i m newbie in android i should ask it here

i need something like this widget....

i don't know exactly what is it?
is a textview or a container for a textview???

please help me find it out. thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: You can achieve this by setting background for the textview with your desired image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a simple textView with a background image to it. Use a 9-patch image for best results when stretched: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Also, this site might help in creating 9-patch images:
http://draw9patch.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is a image used as a background on TextView. You can add any shaped image on background of TextView.

There is a source code available for [Chat bubbles in Android.](http://warting.github.io/AndroidChatBubbles/)